# Pythonic way to test for elements in complex data structures

Tags: python, list, perl, dictionary

** this is a style question, not a "coding problem" **

In Perl, for example, it is intuitive to test for the existence of elements or keys in complicated data structures. If I deserialized a chunk of json like this:

```
[ { 'foo' : 'bar' } ]
```

I would do something like this:

```
if ($array[0]{foo}) {
    print "foo exists\n";
}
if ($array[0]{bar}) {
    print "bar exists\n";
}
```

With this result:

```
$ perl tmp.pl 
foo exists
$
```

How do I do this easily and gracefully in Python?

Comment: What exact data structure are we talking about?

Comment: You mean `if any('foo' in obj for obj in [{'foo': 'bar'}])` ?

Comment: You should be using `exists $array->[0]{foo}` in perl... (And that's not valid JSON, which uses double quotes for strings).

Comment: Its irrelevant what kind of data structure it is, I'm asking in principle.

Comment: @Shawn, Depends. Most of the time, you know the value is either true or absent, in which case you don't need `exists`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an if statement using the `in` keyword:

```
if 'foo' in array[0]:
    print("foo exists")

if 'bar' in array[0]:
    print("bar exists")
```

*FYI `array` is a builtin in python so I'd suggest using a different variable name*

Comment: I like this way. Simple and discrete.

Comment: That's not equivalent to the OP. The OP is performing a truth test, not an existence check.

Comment: OP specifically states they are checking for existence

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't autovivify non-existing container elements, but you can simply catch an exception raised in the event of a `LookupError` (the base class for both `KeyError` and `IndexError`:

```
try:
    array[0]["foo"]
    print("foo exists")
except LookupError:
    pass

try:
    array[0]["bar"]
    print("bar exists")
except LookupError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

```perl
if ($a[0]{foo}) {                     # Perl
   ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```py
if a[0].get("foo"):                   # Python
   ...
```

What if you were checking for existence rather than truth?

```perl
if (exists($a[0]{foo})) {             # Perl
   ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```py
if "foo" in a[0]:                     # Python
   ...
```

---

Note that the above Perl and Python snippets behave differently if the array are empty, but you shouldn't use any of them if the array is empty.

If you wanted to allow empty arrays, you should have been using

```perl
no autovivification;                  # Perl
if ($a[0]{foo}) {
   ...
}
```

or

```perl
if (@a && $a[0]{foo}) {                # Perl
   ...
}
```

The Python equivalent would be one of the following:

```py
if len(a) and a[0].get("foo"):         # Python
   ...
```

```py
if a and len(a) and a[0].get("foo"):   # Python
   ...
```